# Render multiple columns in subreport Telerik

Tags: telerik, report, program-entry-point, column-count

I am creating a Telerik report and in this report I am using few sub reports for some parts of this report. In one portion of the reports I need to display multiple items (detail with description) and it should be render in two columns. To render the content into 2 columns I used the `ColumnCount` property and with this its working fine if I am running the subreport independently. But if I am using this subreport into main report then this `ColumnCount` feature is not working so please let me know how I can render a subreport content into 2 columns.